# Generating TCP-H database for SqlServer 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to populate [TCP-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/default.asp) database for Microsoft SQL Server 2008. 
TPC-H provides a DBGEN tool that can create huge tables according to a schema. By default, it generates text files (one per table) with tuples represented in lines and '|' separating the columns in a tuple and new line for the tuple end.

I need that huge table to be imported in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://dsl.serc.iisc.ernet.in/projects/PICASSO/picasso_download/doc/Installation/SQLServer.htm#load) is the method.